# upload camera functionality doesn’t work on MS Teams task module on android

Tags: html, angular, microsoft-teams

I have an extension in MS Teams, which open a task module - basically an `angular application`. as seen below:

[image]

The functionality of the app is to perform `upload` images.

HTML Code:

```
<input type="file" class="file-input" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" #fileUpload />
```

So, the issue is when I click the button on **ios** it gives me the option to upload from **camera**. But that’s not the case in **android**

After doing some research I tried a couple of options in `HTML`

```
<input accept="image/*" capture type="file" class="file-input" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" #cameraUpload  />
```

or,

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

none of them works inside the teams.

---

Now when I run the app in the browser and click on `file upload` it shows the camera options:

[image]

How can I perform the same functionality inside MS Teams, task module

Answer (score 0):

You can add below permissions to your manifest to support media capabilities:

```
"devicePermissions": [
"media"]


let imageProp: microsoftTeams.media.ImageProps = {
    sources: [microsoftTeams.media.Source.Camera, microsoftTeams.media.Source.Gallery],
    startMode: microsoftTeams.media.CameraStartMode.Photo,
    ink: false,
    cameraSwitcher: false,
    textSticker: false,
    enableFilter: true,
};
let mediaInput: microsoftTeams.media.MediaInputs = {
    mediaType: microsoftTeams.media.MediaType.Image,
    maxMediaCount: 10,
    imageProps: imageProp
};
microsoftTeams.media.selectMedia(mediaInput, (error: microsoftTeams.SdkError, attachments: microsoftTeams.media.Media[]) => {
    if (error) {
        if (error.message) {
            alert(" ErrorCode: " + error.errorCode + error.message);
        } else {
            alert(" ErrorCode: " + error.errorCode);
        }
    }
    if (attachments) {
        let y = attachments[0];
        img.src = ("data:" + y.mimeType + ";base64," + y.preview); }
});
```

Can you please refer below documentation to integrate media capabilities.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/mobile-camera-image-permissions

Git Repo for sample code:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-device-permissions/nodejs

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft does the above API works in desktop version oof MS Teams?

Comment: @GauravGupta -  Currently it does not support on Desktop Teams versions.